# How to align an "inline-block" nicely with an ordered list (ol)

Tags: css, html-lists

I have an alignment problem with my ol list.
I have a simple list like this:

```
<ol type="a">
  <li><button style="display: inline-block">TEXT1</button></li>
  <li><button style="display: inline-block">TEXT2</button></li>
  <li><button style="display: inline-block">TEXT3</button></li>
  <li><button style="display: inline-block">TEXT4</button></li>
</ol>
```

when these text are short, I have the text align next to the order character like this:

[image: look good]

But when the text are longer, it then jump to the next line instead of align on the same line with the order like this:

[image]

*Edit*: As guys pointed out, I missed some attribute for my LI in order to reproduce the problem. Each LI element also has "list-style-position: inside" css, which I think is the source of the problem.

Is there a way to correct it so that the button will align next to the order instead of jumping to the next line?

Comment: The code you've posted isn't enough to reproduce the problem.  A page consisting of just the ordered list you posted, with longer text inserted, shows that the buttons stay next to the list indicators.

Comment: It actually looks good. http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/fNAGr/

Comment: Sorry men, there was a "list-style-position: inside" equipped with these LI element.

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/fNAGr/1/

Comment: This does look good. Is there a way I can make it so that the order (a, b, c) is pinned to the top of the button rather than the bottom?

Comment: Yeah, you can use `vertical-align`.

Comment: @PhươngNguyễn Is this fine? http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/fNAGr/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually looks good. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/fNAGr/). There seems to be other CSS affecting the rendering. Please post the CSS too. If you are worried about having multiple lines, use this:

```
ol li button {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Since you are having a `list-style-position: inside`, you can use this:

```
li {list-style-position: inside;}
li button {width: 90%;}
```

#### Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/fNAGr/1/)

Comment: You rock, man. Still, list-style-position: inside is troublesome. I'm trying to understand why it's there and how to get rid of it. Combine with the vertical, my list would look exactly how I want it. Thanks :)

Comment: (Ehr, the float doesn't look good to me. It complicates the solution.)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I removed it. If you remove the `list-style-position: inside;` it actually works. :)